# How can I de-serialize this json with C#?

Tags: c#, json, list, object

With C#, I try without success to de-serialize this json content :

```
{
    "code":200,
    "message":"OK",
    "name":"The name",
    "description":"The description",
    "tags":{
        "0.1.3":{
            "date":"2015-03-11",
            "author":"SOMEONE",
        },
        "0.1.2":{
            "date":"2015-03-11",
            "author":"SOMEONE",
        }
    }
}
```

You have noticed, there's a list of "tag" objects, but I have not a table.

Beginning of the target classes :

```
[DataContract]
public class Project
{
    [DataMember]
    public int code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string message { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
        **How can I handle tags entries ?**
}

[DataContract]
public class Tag
{
    [DataMember]
    public string date { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string author { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you can validate any json string here http://jsonlint.org/

Comment: Your snippets are not JSON, ask the supplier to send JSON.

Comment: To Jodrell : Entire json content is not listed here, only the section for which I don't know how to make de-serialization.

Comment: With the new info, I believe you can deserialize it using a `Dictionary<string, Tag>`, but I'm not sure if it will automatically work

Comment: `public Dictionary<string, Tag> tags { get; set; }`

Comment: And no, it doesn't work, I already try this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JSON.NET, then you can have the following:

```
[DataContract]
public class Project
{
    [DataMember]
    public int code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string message { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, Tag> tags { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Tag
{
    [DataMember]
    public string date { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string author { get; set; }
}
```

Which then you would use the following way (assuming `responseString` contains your JSON):

```
Project project = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Project>(responseString);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Tag> tag in project.tags)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Version: {0}", tag.Key);
    Debug.WriteLine("Date: {0}", tag.Value.date);
    Debug.WriteLine("Author: {0}", tag.Value.author);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tried the Dictionnary<string, Tag> type but it's not working. The object's count = 0.

Comment: I don't use JsonConvert, only DataContractJsonSerializer. Is there a way to do the job without install the nuget package ?

Comment: @P.Debrabant, I'm sorry, I don't know how DataContractJsonSerializer works. I would still recommend JSON.NET, but it's up to you if you want to use it.

Comment: The important line is: `settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;`

Comment: Thanks for the link, it solves my problem. If I use "settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;" I get the Dictionnary<string, Tag> entries.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON input is valid according to RFC 4627 (JSON specfication).

http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html

Answer (score 0):

JSON sturcture is based on Key Value pair. Correct JSON format is like:

```
{
"object":{
    "DataMember1":"String content",
    "DataMember2":"String content",
    "DataMember3":"String content"
},
"object2":{
    "DataMember1":"String content",
    "DataMember2":"String content"
}
```

}

Goto [basics](http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/)

To check your json structure you can validate from [click here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

Comment: Yes, I know the basics and I have key + value pair. I check the entire format on a validator and it is correct. But how can I manage the content ?

Comment: @P.Debrabant You can use javascript serializer in c# code. For this create a DTO having data member with same as in your json structure. Then you deserialize the json text into class object.

Comment: It's the problem. I can not figure how to handle tags objects. Could you complete the parent class I proposed in my updated post ?

Comment: [link] (http://www.tomasvera.com/programming/using-javascriptserializer-to-parse-json-objects/) @P.Debrabant

Comment: ' [DataContract]
Class CombineClass
{
[DataMember]
public Project objProject {get;set;}
[DataMember]
public List<Tag> objTaglist {get;set;}
}


You Json should be wrapped like this
{
"objProject":
 {
 "code":200,
 "message":"OK",
 "name":"The name",
 "description":"The description"
 },
"objTag":
 {
 "date":"",
 "author":""
 }
} '

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I was able to deserialize:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Project>(json);
```

However, here is my class definition:

```
 public class Project
{

    public string code { get; set; }

    public string message { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public string description { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string,Tag> tags { get; set; }
}


public class Tag
{

    public string date { get; set; }

    public string author { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Arturo Torres Sánchez. To get the "tag" entries, the declaration must be :

```
[DataContract]
public class Project
{
    [DataMember]
    public int code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string message { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, Tag> tags { get; set; }
}
```

And the most important, I must modify the default settings and use the new settings when I create the instance of DataContractJsonSerializer.

```
DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = 
            new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;

DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = 
            new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Project), settings);

Project results = (Project)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

Without the **settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;** tag's object count is 0.